# Alternative option row classes for bootstrap table <tr class="success"> doesn't work. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

i can get this code working with twitter bootstrap

< tr class="success">  according to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables

It should mark table row with green color, but it doesn't work for me. Where can be problem ?

I'm using rails 3 and latest bootstrap gem. Thanks for reply.

edit: code here : http://jsfiddle.net/24RQM/28/

Comment: Did you add the 'table' class to the table?

Comment: It's the same as you can get from link above when you inspect a source. Yes i did. Post edited with source code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old version of Twitter Bootstrap. Move to 2.1.0 and it will work.
See it in action on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simbirsk/g7Z9P/).

**EDIT**
twitter-bootstrap-rails versioning is confusing because gem version doesn't match framework version. So gem version 2.1.1 contains Twitter Bootstrap  version 2.0.4.
To get **Bootstrap v2.1.0** (latest version right now) you have to update **twitter-bootstrap-rails to v2.1.2**

Comment: I wouldn't bother if i hadn't. Gem list says twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.1.1)

Comment: 2.1.1 is the version of your gem, not the version of Bootstrap. Again, what version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Oh, found it: Released gem v.2.1.2 (minor fixes and updated to Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.0)... so move to Bootstrap 2.1.0

Comment: @simbirsk Gem and Bootstrap versions don't match? What a twisted mind created it!

Comment: Simbirsk/mArtinko5MB, can we update this question/answer with the version that was installed and the version you had to move to?  i.e. "I update my Gemfile from vx.x.x to vy.y.y and it fixed the issue"?